# Servidor local para Mac OSX

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

Comprei essa semana meu primeiro. Estou na busca de um servidor local que rode bonitinho no MacBook Pro, porém o que eu uso no Windows (WAMP) não tem versa-o para Mac.

Comment: o osx possui uma distribuição php e apache pré-instalados.. uma desvantagem é que por ser parte do pacote do sistema operacional, geralmente é defasado. Apenas tome cuidado quando for colocar outra instalação para evitar os conflitos com instalações existentes.

Comment: Daniel pode me informar qual que ja vem ckm o sistema??

Comment: Ta mas qual o nome do app? xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WAMP não tem versão para Mac, afinal o W significa "Windows":

**W**indows + **A**pache + **M**ySQL + **P**HP

O que você talvez procure é o MAMP:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP

Assim como usuários de Linux devem procurar o LAMP:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)

**Mas...**
          ... você não está limitado a estas distribuições, a Wikipedia tem uma lista de "AMPs" com várias alternativas, vale à pena dar uma conferida:

**[Wikipedia - AMP Packages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache-MySQL-PHP_packages)**

Comment: Caraca nao tinha a menor ideia disso ahuehsaueuaea valeu mesmo mano xD

Comment: Eu recomendaria o XAMPP, que existe tanto pra Windows como pra OSX.

Comment: Detalhe, o M do MAMP significa Mac, mas também tem pra Windows, hehehe.

Comment: Ah, não deixa de ser um W de cabeça pra baixo :P - Ou será [M]icrosoft Windows? :P x 2

Answer (score -1):

Você pode instalar o apache, php, postgresql, mysql e muitos outros com o https://www.macports.org

Ou melhor, utilizar o https://www.vagrantup.com e subir o seu ambiente em uma VM, assim fica isolado do MACOS.